# .NetCore Show Windows 10 Notification (Toast)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've searched through a number of different posts on how to create toast notifications from .netCore applications, however, none of them helped neither the Microsofts' buggy documentation.

So welling to get a full answer here on how to show a Windows 10 notification (Toast) with an image from a .NetCore console application?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are not targeting .NET 5.0 - this framework is not supported (yet).

Then, install the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package.

Use This and make sure you are setting the Image (**Icon**) full path if you want to show an icon otherwise just pass null.

```
public static void GenerateToast(string appid, string imageFullPath, string h1, string h2, string p1)
{

    var template = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

    var textNodes = template.GetElementsByTagName("text");

    textNodes[0].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(h1));
    textNodes[1].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(h2));
    textNodes[2].AppendChild(template.CreateTextNode(p1));

    if (File.Exists(imageFullPath))
    {
        XmlNodeList toastImageElements = template.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement)toastImageElements[0]).SetAttribute("src", imageFullPath);
    }
    IXmlNode toastNode = template.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
    ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

    var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(appid);
    var notification = new ToastNotification(template);

    notifier.Show(notification);
}
```

Comment: It worked fine on .NET Core 3.1 and 3.0 in my tests.

Comment: Not working in .NET 6.0